# Python script works in Spyder and CMD but not Atom or Git Bash

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, spyder, atom-editor

I have this code

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://www.protocols.io/api/v3/protocols?filter=%20public%20&order_field=relevance&key=%20gel%22electrophoresis%20'

r = requests.get(url)
jason = r.json()

print (jason)
```

Which works in Spyder(3.7) and running it in windows cmd but not when in Atom or git bash. I get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\James\Documents\ProtocolScaper\test_3.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(jason)
  File "C:\Users\James\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 5399-5400: character maps to <undefined>
```

For my applications, I really need this to run in Atom 
Any ideas?

Comment: I just ran your code on my machine, using Atom, and it worked fine.  Have you tried running it on your mac just using the python interpreter from the command line?  Typing each line of code. When I did that I had a problem with the first line - import requests - which I had to correct to get it to work.

Comment: @jmh Thanks for looking into this, this seems to be a windows specific issue based on the codec cp1252. I fixed this by encoding into cp1252 then decoding with cp1252/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemeed to be a windows specific issue with cp1252 encoding. Fixed by

```
jason.encode('cp1252, 'replace').decode('cp1252')
```